# How to detect Celery task which doing similar job before run another task?

Tags: python, celery, ipc

My celery task is doing time-consuming calculations on some database-stored entity.  Workflow is like this: get information from database, compile it to some serializable object, save object. Other tasks are doing other calculations (like rendering images) on loaded object.

But serialization is time-consuming, so i'd like to have one task per one entity running for a while, which holds serialized object in memory and process client requests, delivered through messaging queue (redis pubsub). If no requests for a while, task exits. After that, if client need some job to be done, it runs another task, which loads object, process it and stay tuned for a while for other jobs. This task should check at startup, if it only one worker on this particular entity to avoid collisions. **So what is best strategy to check is there another task running for this entity?**

1) First idea is to send message to some channel associated with entity, and wait for response. Bad idea, target task can be busy with calculations and waiting for response with timeout is just wasting time.

2) Store celery task-id in db is even worse - task can be killed, but record will stay, so we need to ensure that target task is alive.

3) Third idea is to inspect workers for running tasks, checking it state for entity id (which task will provide at startup). Also seems, that some collisions can happens, i.e. if several tasks are scheduled, but not runing yet.

For now I think idea 1 is the best with modifications like this: task will send message to entity channel on startup with it's startup time, but then immediately starts working, not waiting for response. Then it checks message queue and if someone is respond they compare timestamps and task with bigger timestamp quits. Seems complicated enough, are there better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Final solution is to start supervisor thread in task, which reply to 'discover' message from competing tasks.

So workflow is like that.

1. Task starts, then subscribes to Redis PubSub channel with entity ID
2. Task sends 'discover' message to channel
3. Task wait a little bit
4. Task search 'reply' in incoming messages in channel, if found exits.
5. Task starts supervisor thread, which reply by 'reply' to all incoming 'discover' messages

This works fine except several tasks start simultaneouly, i.e. after worker restart. To avoid this need to make subscription proccess atomic, using Redis lock:

```
class RedisChannel:
    def __init__(self, channel_id):
        self.channel_id = channel_id
        self.redis = StrictRedis()
        self.channel = self.redis.pubsub()
        with self.redis.lock(channel_id):
            self.channel.subscribe(channel_id)
```